# Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

Suddenly my sharepoint site showing this error "Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) "

I am running my site on MOSS 2007 (version 12.0.6425.1000) and SQL server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error but running **SharePoint 2007** on **Windows Server 2003 SP2** with **SQL 2005** as the database. This is an organisation environment where all users access SharePoint intranet via the domain so I gave access to the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` account access as a `db_owner` to the SharePoint content database, Search database and that eliminated the error.